# AutoHotKey pause part of the script

Tags: autohotkey, pause, numpad

I've got a script running which binds numpad numbers to inline numbers (in order to easily add Unicode chars on the fly because I'm on a laptop without the numpad) and that also binds Home and End to Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right respectively. Now, the whole script can be paused by pressing the Apps key, but I'd like the numpad bindings to be the only part toggled and keep Ctrl+Arrows binding always running instead. How can I modify this script to do that?

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

^Left::Send {Home}
+^Left::Send {LShift down}{Home}{LShift up}
^Right::Send {End}
+^Right::Send {LShift down}{End}{LShift up}

0::Numpad0
1::Numpad1
2::Numpad2
3::Numpad3 
4::Numpad4
5::Numpad5
6::Numpad6
7::Numpad7
8::Numpad8
9::Numpad9

Appskey::
Suspend,Toggle
return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
#SingleInstance Force

 ; These hotkeys are always active (even if the script is suspended):

^Left::
    Suspend Toggle
    Send {Home}
    Suspend Toggle
return

+^Left::
    Suspend Toggle
    Send {LShift down}{Home}{LShift up}
    Suspend Toggle
return

^Right::
    Suspend Toggle
    Send {End}
    Suspend Toggle
return

+^Right::
    Suspend Toggle
    Send {LShift down}{End}{LShift up}
    Suspend Toggle
return

Appskey:: Suspend,Toggle


; These hotkeys are inactive if the script is suspended:

0::Numpad0
1::Numpad1
2::Numpad2
3::Numpad3
4::Numpad4
5::Numpad5
6::Numpad6
7::Numpad7
8::Numpad8
9::Numpad9
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Suspend.htm#Remarks:

> Any hotkey/hotstring subroutine whose very first line is Suspend
>   (except Suspend On) will be exempt from suspension. In other words,
>   the hotkey will remain enabled even while suspension is ON. This
>   allows suspension to be turned off via such a hotkey.

Comment: Thanks, but the script does the same thing as before: suspending the script via the Apps key (turns the green H into an S in the tray bar) suspends all the script and not just the numpad bindings.

Comment: It perfectly works now, thank you! I see you're calling "Suspend Toggle" twice on every Ctrl+Arrows hit. Could it possibly harm any performance? I think not, but wanted to ask. Thank you again

Comment: I don't think so either, because the script returns (exits from this subroutine, terminating the current thread) immediately after executing the last command.